# Can Philips Hue lights slow down my WiFi? If so, how can I prevent it?

Tags: wireless-networking

I recently purchased Philips Hue lights and noticed that my wireless network has slowed down considerably. If I cut power to all lights and the Hue bridge, everything seems to be fine again.

Hue lights work on the ZigBee protocol, which uses the 2.4 GHz band and so does my WiFi, but I don't think that they communicate permanently. What could be the source of the problem? RF interference coming from the LED driver?

How can I mitigate this effect?

PS: I'm not sure in which SO site I should post this...

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the Hue Bridge from your Router but leaving it switched on?  Does that still slow down the WiFi?

Comment: I'd think about 5GHz WiFi - it's far less crowded.

Answer (score 1):

The Philips Hue is also a wireless device so it's absolutely possible that it's disrupting the router. You should try setting a different channel for your router which you can set inside your router's control area (i.e. something like 192.168.2.1 from any browser)

Comment: Philips Hue is not a wifi device. It uses the ZigBee protocol and the Hue bridge only works with Ethernet.

Comment: The bridge part of Philips hue is the wifi device, not the bulbs themselves.

Comment: Where do you get this information from? A google search only shows that you *have* to connect it to a router via Ethernet and there are no settings in the app that indicate it is a wifi device.

Comment: Check out the technical specs for the bridge: http://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/046677456214/hue-white-and-color-ambiance/specifications. It says frequency band: 2400-2483.5, that means it's a wifi device.

Comment: That frequency refers to the ZigBee protocol, not wifi. ZigBee uses the same spectrum as wifi, but is a different protocol. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee#Radio_hardware

Comment: When I said Wifi I meant wireless, so your playing with words here, but if you think a bit they both use the same radio signals, so that's why you're experiencing the interference, you just need to change the channels so they're not on the same.

Comment: Still, it's a different thing. :-) I found this and will try if adjusting works: http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Channels,_Zigbee

Comment: It's a different protocol, but it's still firing on all 4 cylinders right down the same street as your wifi... just like the TV & microwave can do.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a wifi device or a desk fan... if it's producing EMI on the 2.4GHz band it can interfere with radio signals on the 2.4GHz band. Many of the sources of EMI in the 2.4GHz band are not from radio communications at all but "noisy" household appliances (microwaves, fluorescent lights, vacuum cleaners, etc). It can be a different protocol all day long... it changes nothing in this respect. This is one of the reason WiFi device manufacturers are pushing use of the 5GHz band more and more.